Positive integers $n$ such that $ n= 37\times$ times the digit sum of $n$
ARML 2021 I-5 , Sum of digits :

For a positive integer $n$, let $s(n)$ denote the sum of the digits of $n$.
Compute the sum of all positive integers $n$ for which $n = 37s(n)$.

It's easy to derive that the number of digits of such a number will be $3$.
Then we solve for $100A + 10B + C = 37(A + B + C)$,  which implies $7A = 3B + 4C$.
From this it's elementary to obtain these solutions
$111,222,333,\dots,999,370,407$.
But in this I missed $4$ solutions - $481,518,629, 592$
I am unable to understand the official solution as there they came up with a general solution using co-ordinate geometry.
Is there any algebraic method to find the general solution?
This is the part of the official solution which I can't understand:

Fix $A$ to be a constant and imagine moving along the line $7A = 3B + 4C$ in the (B,C)-coordinate plane from any lattice point on the line to the next lattice point on the line. Such a movement requires a translation of 4 units to the right and 3 down or a translation of 4 units to the left and 3 up due to the slope of the line. In fact, if $(b, c)$ is a solution to $7A = 3B + 4C$, then it is the only solution on the line strictly between the points $(b−4, c+3)$ and $(b+4, c−3)$ (which are both solutions).
Thus it follows that $7A = 3B + 4C$ has the general solution
$(A, B, C)=(A, A + 4t, A − 3t)$.


Can you see why the equation $7A=3B+4C$ implies that $C-B$ is a multiple of $7$? Once you have that, you can just go through the cases.

Algebraic solution:
$$100A+10B+C=37(A+B+C)$$
Rearranging,
$$63A=27B+36C$$
so
$$7A=3B+4C$$
You can use modular arithmetic here, or just divide both sides by $7$:
$$A=\frac{3B+4C}{7}=\frac{7B+4C-4B}{7}=B+\frac{4}{7}(C-B)$$
So we conclude that $C-B$ is a multiple of $7$. Since $B$ and $C$ are decimal digits, $C-B$ can only be $-7$, $0$ or $7$.

Case $C-B=0$:
In this case $A=B=C$ - ie the nine solutions $111,222,\ldots,999$.

Case $C-B=-7$:
Now $A=B-4$ and $C=B-7$. This gives the solutions $370$, $481$ and $592$.

Case $C-B=7$:
Now $A=B+4$ and $C=B+7$. This gives the solutions $407$, $518$ and $629$.

It's perhaps a bit surprising that out of $25$ multiples of $37$ with three digits, $15$ are solutions to this.

We have for $a,b,c \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ that $7a=3b+4c$. Take the equation $\bmod 4$ to get $a\equiv_4 b$ and and take it $\bmod 3$ to get $a\equiv_3 c$. Thus write $b=4N+a$ and $c=3M+a$ for integer parameters $N$ and $M$. Substitute back into the equation to get $7a=3(4N+a)+4(3M+a)$ which becomes $N=-M=k$. Thus, $b=4k+a$ and $c=a-3k$ where $k$ is an integer parameter.
So for any choice of $a$, we have $(a,b,c):(a,4k+a,a-3k)$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$.
